# How to create an array that would contain only elements within items elements that contain "ball" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to create an array that contain the item "ball" from the item items?

```js
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];
```

Comment: You've tagged this with `filter`, so it seems you already know how to do it. Please show us the code you tried, and describe how it failed.

Comment: Do not paste your attempt as a comment!  Place it into your original question, and apply proper code formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `filter` method to select only the items that you want. In this case like this.

```
array.filter(o=>o.items.includes('ball'));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use mine:

```js
const array = [
  {
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];

const ballArr = array.filter((item) => item.items.includes("ball"));

console.log(ballArr);
```

Comment: @theWellHopeErr already posted this method with `filter`.

Comment: Just because I do the details for you to easily imagine :v

Comment: @tranminhquang What details do you refer to? Your answer has *less* explanation than the existing one

Comment: Because I'm in a hurry: I just code it to give correct results